# Find partial class names in spans with Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

This page https://www.kijiji.ca/v-1-bedroom-apartments-condos/ville-de-montreal/1-chambre-chauff-eau-chaude-incl-vsl-514-856-0038/1334431659 contains this span class:

```
<span class="currentPrice-3131760660"><span content="800.00">800,00 $</span>
```

I'm trying to automatically extract the price (800$ in this case). Over time, however, the number after "currentPrice-" changes, and my Python script ceases to work. I am using this Beautiful soup function:

```
soup.find_all('span', {'class' : 'currentPrice-3131760660'})
```

How can I use find_all to extract partial matches of class names, such as all classes containing the string "currentPrice-"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try a CSS selector `soup.select('span[class*="currentPrice-"]')`

Answer (score 19):

According to the [docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#the-keyword-arguments) you have several options:

- Use a regex:

  ```
  soup.find_all('span', attrs={'class': re.compile('^currentPrice.*')})
  ```
- Use a function:

  ```
  soup.find_all('span',
                attrs={'class': lambda e: e.startswith('currentPrice') if e else False})
  ```