# extract data-src value from img tag with specific attributes

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am writing python code to extract value of data-src from certain img tag with certain attributes.I am using class attribute but it has different values in it.

here are the two sample from where i am extracting.

```
<img class="img-fluid lazy"  data-src="https://d1bng4dn08r9r5.cloudfront.net/contents/cover-1588341903.png"
alt="Happy 1st day of the month"
src="https://www.simrankaurapp.com/img/icons/default-img.png" />

<img class="img-fluid lazy blur-img image5ea68b9463389011485bf592" 
      data-src="https://d1bng4dn08r9r5.cloudfront.net/contents/cover-1587973008.jpg"
alt="Everyday is more than just tongue-out tuesday"
src="https://www.simrankaurapp.com/img/icons/default-img.png" />
```

And here is my code

```
elements = soup.findAll('img',{'class', 'img-fluid lazy'})
for element in elements:
    print(element['data-src'])
```

I want to grab both url in txt file but unable to do so.The page also has infinite scroll and i want to reach the bottom if the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current code matches the exact class, but the second image tag has additional classes to it. 

So you can try using regex to match it, hope it helps.

```
import re
```

```
soup.find_all('img', {'class': re.compile('^img-fluid lazy.*')})
```

You can find more here: 
[Find partial class names in spans with Beautiful Soup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52842778/find-partial-class-names-in-spans-with-beautiful-soup)