# Find a html element using part of the class name?

Tags: python, html, class, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm using python's BeautifulSoup library to scrape text, but I want to scrape all the elements which have part of the class name.

So if multiple elements had the words "ProductCard", but each element had a slightly different arrangement of letters preceding (e.g. "ProductCard-HbksbD", "ProductCard-UfbraH") - is there a way to get all of them?

```
for item in soup.find_all('a', {'class': 'ProductCard'}):
    print(item)
```

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52842778/find-partial-class-names-in-spans-with-beautiful-soup

Comment: @vmouffron Yes! Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

I believe python's BeautifulSoup library supports CSS Selectors, so you can use this:

```
for item in soup.select('a[class*="ProductCard"]'):
    print(item)
```