# How can I get the contents of span elements with a specific class suffix?

Tags: html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm admit that i am really noob at scraping the web by using Bs4.
So here the problem i'm facing. I got this html file.
All i want is getting a **number** from all **span** contains with suffix **-confirmed-vn**

```html
....
<div class="board-content--left">
    <div class="board-detail">
        <div class="board-col col1 text-blue">
            Cases<br>
            <div style="margin-right:10px;">
                <span class="live-confirmed-vn">15115 </span>
                <span class="plus-confirmed-vn">+578</span>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="board-col col2">
            <div class="board-col-child">
                Recovered:
                <span class="live-recovered-vn"> 5949</span>
                <span class="plus-recovered-vn">+0</span>
            </div>
            <div class="board-col-child">
                Deaths:
                <span class="live-death-vn"> 74 </span>
                <span class="plus-death-vn"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
</div>
```

This is what i'm doing now

```py
import re
import request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://thanhnien.vn/e-magazine/toan-canh-covid-19-tin-tuc-so-lieu-phan-tich-1265104.html"
# url contains html that contain structure above
req = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text,features="html.parser")
test = soup.find_all('span', class_=re.compile(r'.+-confirmed-vn'))
print(test)
```

```
#print(test)

[<span class="live-confirmed-vn"></span>, <span class="plus-confirmed-vn"></span>, <span class="live-confirmed-vn text-red"></span>, <span class="live-confirmed-vn"></span>, <span class="live-confirmed-vn text-red"></span>, <span class="live-confirmed-vn"></span>]
```

Comment: Neither a Python nor a BeautifulSoup expert, but this question kind of sounds like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52842778/find-partial-class-names-in-spans-with-beautiful-soup). Maybe it'll get you going?

Comment: @thordarson Thanks for your help. Unfortunately, its only show the span class, not the number i want :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = """<div class="board-content--left">
    <div class="board-detail">
        <div class="board-col col1 text-blue">
            Cases<br>
            <div style="margin-right:10px;">
                <span class="live-confirmed-vn">15115 </span>
                <span class="plus-confirmed-vn">+578</span>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="board-col col2">
            <div class="board-col-child">
                Recovered:
                <span class="live-recovered-vn"> 5949</span>
                <span class="plus-recovered-vn">+0</span>
            </div>
            <div class="board-col-child">
                Deaths:
                <span class="live-death-vn"> 74 </span>
                <span class="plus-death-vn"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
</div>"""


soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

print([x.text for x in soup.select('span[class$=confirmed-vn]')])
```

Output:

```
['15115 ', '+578']
```

Comment: Hi. First off all, thanks for the answer you give me. IT working great. Now im facing another issue, is the content from my url is only show number,content when Javascript is turn on. That mean BeatifulSoup4 is not working ( beacuse iirc, BS4 is only work with HTML\CSS only). Now i need to find a way to resolve that issue.

Comment: @QHarr Ok i just resolve my problem by install Selenium. Thanks you